# How to check "Enable Aura Component Access Fix" winter 22 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, winter21, release-update

Can anyone please guide me how to check whether "Enable Aura Component Access Fix" Winter'22 release update will impact my org. If it impacts what changes do I need to perform to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

There are few points to consider.

1. This update was first made available in Summer ’21 and is enforced in Winter ’22.
2. This wont affect if you are building a non managed package solution.
3. This is still not enforced automatically.

Now in your scratch org or sandboxes you can follow this step and enable this.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_security_ru.htm&type=5&release=234

Things should work fine if you are using the component for **NOT** managed package development. But if you plan to create a managed package and you are using the component in the subscriber org then it would be an issue as `access` as public will only allow this component to be used in same namespace.